# Should I be returning weak/shared_ptrs or unique_ptr's to my resources?

Tags: game-mechanics, sfml, c++

A friend of mine told me instead of normal pointers, I should use unique_ptr, i asked him why unique_ptr's if some resources are going to be shares, like multiple grass tiles, or enemies. I currently use this:

```
    std::map<ResourceTextures /* this is just a int */, 
    std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture>> _textures;
```

Shouldn't I be using shared_ptr instead? That way I can keep the reference count, and unload resources as they have 0 references?

Also one more question, currently, I am passing my resource manager in every file, is there a way to make it so that all my functions dont require this:

```
Level(ResourceManager& resMan);
Tiles(ResourceManager& resMan);
```

A level is an array or tiles, should i just make it inherit tiles, so that i don't have to pass around my resourceManager everywhere?

Thanks for the help guys, after 2 years of doing nothing programming, I'm trying to make a simple game!

Comment: This seems to be purely a programming question—how about asking on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared pointers/reference-counted pointers are the correct way of handling data who's lifetime needs to be, well, shared `:)`.

`unique_ptr` means "this object will have only one owner at any given time, when the owner goes away, that object is destroyed with it", while `shared_ptr` means "this object can have many simultaneous owners, the last owner holding a pointer to it that goes away cleans up the object with it".

Now a word of caution: go easy on the shared resources. A shared pointer is in many ways a glorified global variable, and excessive use global data makes for [spaghetti and meatballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) kind of code.

---

> Also one more question, currently, I am passing my resource manager in every file, is there a way to make it so that all my functions don't require this...

**Don't change that!**

You're doing the right thing by making dependencies explicit. Always prefer passing dependencies via function parameters, it will make your code easier to reason about and easier to test!

Answer (score 3):

Going with a pure standard library approach, `shared_ptr` is the best tool you have for resources. Yes, you want to share resources between all the objects that use them.

I personally dislike `shared_ptr` and generally use a custom ref-counted handle for cases where I really need them, such as with resource handles. There's various features that are *really* handy that `shared_ptr` lacks such as the ability to track who is holding onto all those references (so you can track down reference "leaks" and the like).

Some engines also prefer to merge a few different bits of information into their resource handles, at least in some cases. An engine may want to have streaming load operations so their `Load` functions can't actually return a `shared_ptr` directly and need an extra `future` or some other mechanism tied into their resource handles. Other engines prefer tying the resource name into the handle. None of these are necessary, though.

You shouldn't need to pass your resource manager to a lot of places. For instance, I can't think of many reasons that a `Tiles` class would need one. Likewise, a `LeveL` class only needs the resource manager when you're loading the level and not again. Since there are very specific call chains that need the resource manager you can try moving the parameter to just those functions, which can simplify your code and unbloat your structures quite a bit.